# how to retrive customer details for success page

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments

[image]Please I need help with how can I retrieve customer details like name amount on my success URL after stripe payment. need some example pls if you could create a success page with javascript to get details from backend to front end so I can understand how it works and if my backend needs some changes for retrieving please do shade some light

here are my codes for server-side PHP slim is the framework that I am using

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Stripe\Stripe;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

require './config.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    Stripe::setApiKey(getenv('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
    return $next($request, $response);
});

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  return $response->write(file_get_contents(getenv('STATIC_DIR') . './grid-test.html','/index-copy.html'));
});

$app->post('/checkout_sessions', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app)  {
  $params = json_decode($request->getBody());
  $payment_method_types = [
    'usd' => ['card'],
    'eur' => ['card'],
    'cad' => ['card']
  ];
  $products = [
    'test' => 'prod_test',
  ];

  $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/?cancel=true',
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'payment_intent_data' => [
      'metadata' => [
        'package' => $params->package,
        'date' => $params->datepicker,
        'no of adults' => $params->adults,
        'no of children' => $params->children,
        'occupancy' => $params->occupancy,
        'tour' => $params->tour,
        'location' => $params->location,
      ]
    ],
    'metadata' => [
      'package' => $params->package,
      'date' => $params->datepicker,
      'no of adults' => $params->adults,
      'no of children' => $params->children,
      'occupancy' => $params->occupancy,
      'tour' => $params->tour,
      'location' => $params->location,
    ],
    'submit_type' => 'donate',
    'line_items' => [[
      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => 'aed',
        'product' => $products[$params->package],
        'unit_amount' => $params->amount,
      ],
      'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'phone_number_collection' => [
      'enabled' => true,
    ],
    
  ]);

  return $response->withJson([
    'id' => $session->id
  ]);
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Did you look at the example php success page [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#create-success-page)?

Comment: i did try this all i get is text with same thing written on page

Comment: Yes, it only uses $customer->name in the example.  But the customer object has more details, and the checkout session object contains the details of the order.

Comment: this is what i get (above picture is edit) when i try according to guide

Comment: It doesn't look like that page is executed through a PHP interpreter - it's just dumping the contents of the file.

Comment: @MZainAsif, you can pass the user data into session while entering the billing address. And after the form submit, you can show customer data from the session.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only returns id to the view i.e

```
return $response->withJson(['id' => $session->id]);
```

You should pass the customer details to the view something like

```
 return $response->withJson([
 'id' => $session->id,
 'customer' => $customerObject
 ]);
```

And on the view, render the cutomer object

Comment: if you could give example of how to render in HTML it would be great help pls

Comment: its not working as i did this stripe checkout stopped working 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COeMEHKbECw&list=WL&index=124

I saw this video if anyone could do same for PHP slim